# How to manage URL's between subdomain and the main domain

Tags: php, url

I am having trouble keeping all my links working.

```
/home
    includes/    
    public/  
       secure/
       index.php  
       src/  
          style.css
```

At the moment I write all my URL's starting with `/` and I work my way outward `ie: /public/src/style.css`. The problem is that I have added a subdomain `secure` and this points to a different folder. Now, all my URL's dont work because the `/public/src/style.ss` does not exist in the subdomain's directory.

I dont want to hard code all my URLs, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why have you added a subdomain `secure` in the first place? What purpose does it serve? (With the structure you show, you'll have no choice but to point to the full main domain: `http://domain.com`....

Comment: umm, if you start all your URLs with `/` and work your way out, then you shouldn't have a problem.  Your problem looks like you *aren't* doing what you say you do - which you point out exactly that, by showing how you *aren't* doing that with `src/style.css`

Comment: @Pekka웃 what else can I do?

Comment: Why do you need the subdomain?

Comment: @CrayonViolent sorry, updated. I am strict on it, the problem is the SERVER NAME is different

Comment: @Pekka웃 to process credit cards on a secure connection, I wanted to use a certificate with `secure.mydomain.com`

Comment: Ah. Then you'll have to hardcode `mydomain.com` into the URLs. There's no other way

Comment: well if you want to truly make it secure, all of your files included on your page will need to be secure as well.  So you will need to dupe all your files into your `secure` dir

Comment: Ah, @Crayon makes a fair point. True.

Comment: @CrayonViolent you're right, how could I forget that. Is it usual to copy them all over?

Comment: @CrayonViolent doesnt sound very good practice to keep copying every time there is a change! Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, it's not unusual to have a separate instance of the files. It wouldn't be that hard to maintain if they are versioned and draw from the same repo.  Alternatively you could just have one instance in the secure dir and change your unsecure pages to point to them

Comment: @Pekka웃 and hardcoding is even harder when switching between localhost and my online server

Comment: Symlink the dirs with shared data & done.

Comment: @CrayonViolent cool, thanks for the tips! Think I will create an automated system that copies them over!

Comment: Side note: your directory setup isn't 100% ideal. I can access everything inside `secure` through a non-secure connection when using `domain.com/secure/....` something to bear in mind

Comment: @Pekka웃 thanks, so shall I place the folder outside of the root directory?

Comment: @Wrikken thanks, checkingn it out

Comment: Yeah, that would be advisable

Comment: for example, the full server path for your `www` public root might be `/var/www/htdocs/`  so you should follow the convention of your server dir structure and do `/var/secure/htdocs/`

Comment: @Pekka웃 could you really access everything inside `secure` even if I checked if HTTPS is `off` and if it is `off` then I redirected you to `https://secure.domain.com`?

Comment: I guess not, but it's not good style to have a subdomain be a sub-directory of another domain either way. If it's not too much hassle, I would change it.

Comment: @Wrikken brilliant idea, just got it working in Windows. Now to hope that it works on a shared Linux server on Hostgator ;) thanx

Comment: @Wrikken I see that hard links dont work on directories in Unix http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22394/why-hard-links-not-allowed-to-directories-in-unix-linux/22406#22406, would a soft directory link be good enough?

Comment: Yes, I'd prefer them actually.

Answer (score 0):

/public/src/style.css shouldnt work at all because public according to your schematic isnt in the root directory. and adding in the / is saying it is.

According to your schematic, home is in the root directory so my first example should work to link as you want to but there are two others that work just the same.

In order to access with that link you need to do one of these options:

```
/home/public/src/style.css

../src/style.css

http://example.com/src/style.css
```